# How to manage the world through the minecraft plugin?

Tags: java, minecraft

I can manage player with

```
Player p = (Player) sender
p.*
```

* - player manage funcions.

I can manage world? For example: change time.

Comment: assuming you are using Forge: try [Documentation](http://mcforge.readthedocs.io/) - but kind of broad topic (influence on animations; side-effects, ...) (you can also search some open-source mod that is doing something similar and check its code)

Comment: Forge, Bukkit, MCP, what?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the world object with: `World w = player.getWorld()`

Now you can execute methods onto the world object, for example `w.setTime(2000)`

See the documentation for methods: https://jd.bukkit.org/org/bukkit/World.html